# Zend Framework 1.12 - can not load module's model

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-autoloader

I have Zend Framework 1.12 application with several modules. So far everything worked well. But I wanted to add mappers to my application and Zend Framework can not find mapper class.

Structure of the project:

```
-application
   -modules
     -api
     -otms
       -models
         -Mapper
           FormToOnix2.php
         -FeedFile.php
```

Mapper file looks like:

```
class Otms_Model_Mapper_FormToOnix2
{
   ...
}
```

In application.ini I added "Otms_" prefix for autoloading:

```
autoloaderNamespaces.otms[]   = "Otms_"
```

But when I try to create mapper object from controller

```
 $test = new Otms_Model_Mapper_FormToOnix2();
```

I receive the following error message

```
include_once(Otms/Model/Mapper/FormToOnix2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/cloudware/library/Zend/Loader.php</b> on line 146
```

At the same time if I try to create object of another Otms model, like :

```
$file = new Otms_Model_FeedFile();
```

Everything works fine. How to fix problem with mapper loading?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I read [Zend Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html) about autoloader and module resources loader. So,

```
Zend Framework ships with a concrete implementation of Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource            
that contains resource type mappings that cover the default recommended 
the directory structure for Zend Framework MVC applications.
```

And this mapping scheme look like this:

```
forms/       => Form
models/      => Model
    DbTable/ => Model_DbTable
    mappers/ => Model_Mapper
plugins/     => Plugin
services/    => Service
views/
    helpers  => View_Helper
    filters  => View_Filter
```

So, if you want to add a directory with mappers you should name it "Mappers" not "Mapper". That solved my problem.